# return bbp_get_topic_author_id as integer

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, bbpress

As the title suggests I would like to receive the topic author as an integer I am using it in conjunction with myCRED, so far, I have tried this:

```
$user_id = bbp_get_topic_author_id(  $topic_id = 0 );
$mycred  = mycred();

if ( ! $mycred->exclude_user( $user_id ) )
    $mycred->update_users_balance( $user_id, 1 );
```

I assumed bbp_get_topic_author_id returned a integer like `get_current_user_id` but the script acted as if the line didn't exist and continued with the rest of the plugin. This makes me assume that it is returning some variable but cannot be understood by mycred. Thanks in advance.

P.S I am unsure what to tag this so I have only selected bbpress

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$user_id = bbp_get_topic_author_id(  $topic_id = 0 )` is malformed. You need to remove the `= 0` from `$topic_id = 0` and make sure that the variable `$topic_id` actually contains the ID of the topic you are trying to get the author of.

Comment: Thanks. I have done this and added `$topic_id = bbp_get_topic_id();` above the other code, but it doesn't update the points and passes through the rest of the plugin. Sorry if I am being stupid.

Comment: Have you confirmed that all else in your code is being populated properly? Eg, if you var_dump `$topic_id`, `$user_id` and `$mycred` do you see what you expect? I don't recognise the function `mycred()`, so perhaps the problem is happening in there? Where is it defined? Is it yours or part of another plugin?